# QR RECEIVED <some code> . How to connect to whatsapp web with this code? whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, qr-code, whatsapp

This spams in console when i run my code . `Module - whatsapp-web.js`

**CODE**

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    // Generate and scan this code with your phone
    console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
});



client.on('message', async(msg) => {
    const mentions = await msg.getMentions();

    for (let contact of mentions) {
        console.log(`${contact.pushname} was mentioned`);
    }
});

client.initialize();
```

How to connect to whatsapp web with this module ?

**CONSOLE**

```
QR received 
1@wCO3HYi6B1wat+cAyHe3+tlzfbjiWNxCTP30fEY16YNgmaBuknL/bBDpMNzA2SgfFPfCgQ==,yycd40PiAgEvrk961s+wiBLoMlsFb/eqVpRTN9Ec3FE=,E37yNJ5fmhoX3G/A==
```

Something like the above appear in console .

Comment: Generate a QR code with that text (`1@wC…A==`) and scan it using WhatsApp.

Comment: Ty @D.Pardal . i already solved with another module qrcode-terminal.   .. should i delete this post? i have solved this issue .. I'm asking because i'm new to stackoverflow..

Comment: You should answer your own question and explain how you solved it, in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Ooh ok but it shows like this :( `We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.`

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/388250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the thing

```
$ npm i qrcode-terminal
```

then

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');

const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', qr => {
qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();
```

Comment: After scaning QR succesfully, no change for me... no sending: Client is ready!

Comment: Each run I should scan again

Answer (score -1):

follow above answer after run code some qrcode image will generate on your console.next you go to your whatsapp select 'Linked devices' from under the three dotted right top  icon .here you should scan the console generated qrimage .now it is ready to send and recive msg